# How to get better timing data in python-requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Python-requests is great, but I'd like to get a bit more detail from the response.

If I do:

```
    for url in urls:
      r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
      print r.elapsed
```

I get something like ':00:00.246230' which is the response time in microseconds. So far, so cool.

In curl -v --tracetime, I can break out the time to first byte, SSL handshake, and the timestamp of the headers and body. Any way to get the same from the python-requests response object?

Comment: There is no other instrumentation present. This would require in-depth hacking, or a feature request.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case, but I was hoping someone would just say all I need is the super-secret underlying method thingy. Normally I'd use requests for everything, but in this case I need the SSL timing.

Answer (score -1):

That's technically not possible and it would take a great deal of work in urllib3 first. Even so, this feature would be very difficult to work into requests since there is far more you can do with a Response object than just download data like in curl.

Comment: I disagree - it is technically possible, just not without hacking the requests library. Just because you can do more with a Response object, doesn't mean it can't provide these timings for when you do download data.

Comment: @Ben you're living in a world of delusion. The SSL handshake takes place in urllib3 and has no exposition inside of requests. How will hacking requests provide that information? The time until you receive first byte is only traceable inside of urllib3, so thinking you can simply hack requests is wishful thinking